# Converting Music Frequencies

Tags: music, pitch

I heard about the benefits of 528Hz music, and I heard that is possible to change the music frequency.

So, I'm interested in a way to change the normal frequency (A440Hz) to A444Hz (C528Hz) or A432Hz (C256Hz).

Comment: In what form does the music currently exist?

Comment: What do you mean? (: frequency or format??

Comment: I looked into an idea about 528Hz music that someone was "somehow" equating to the wavelength of light and basically it is total rubbish. Maybe you can supply a link that you've read.

Comment: well, i have read 528 records website .. and then, i just googled: 528hz, and so on .. conversion, pitch shifting .. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pitch shift music, but it will produce unnatural artifacts in the audio will apply an equivalent shift to all frequencies within the audio.  It just takes the existing waveform and slows it down or speeds it up as necessary to alter the frequency.  There are many, many options for how to do it.  A simple search for "pitch shift software" and your file format and operating system should return numerous results that will allow for pitch shifting.

Comment: Do you know any good pitch shifting software?? p.s: does it stay in the tempo and understandable??

Comment: Any decent pitch shifting software will correct for tempo and should be understandable, but like I said, there are unavoidable artifacts as it has to invent a new waveform to correct of the stretching or compression of the waveform.

Answer (score 1):

A number of keyboard synthesizers will allow you to shift the entire keyboard from standard concert pitch 440HZ tuning to plus and minus several steps, so that you can shift the whole system with one mighty button. You should be able to tune your synth so that c5=528 Hz. You could tune your guitar this way too, but you should use a calibrated source whether that is electronic or acoustic (tuning fork).

Likewise, some synths have a feature that will allow you to do more than that including changing from a equal temperament system to other systems such as illustrated in the following chart from a Yamaha Synth owners manual:

http://www.manualslib.com/manual/196958/Yamaha-S90-Es.html?page=147

You might want to explore natural just intonation scales based on a C5 = 528 Hz, you will not be able to modulate as in Bach since this is no longer equal temperament but certainly mono-tonic music will be fine as long as it based on a tonic with an octive C5 that = 528 Hz.

528 Music has a huge web presence linking healing, love, DNA, and many other things to pitch and non-equal temperament tuning. Here is an example:

http://www.redicecreations.com/specialreports/2006/01jan/solfeggio.html

If you want to play so called 528 Hz Music, I don't think a pitch shifter will help you as it will shift everything one way or another equally and since there is more here than just a C5=528 Hz, you need to change the tuning system from equal temperament to what the above article refers to as the "Solfeggio Scale".

UPDATE:
An attempt to debunk or sort out health claims etc about 528 Hz music here:

http://freeindependentsun.com/healing/the-solfeggio-scale-528hz-c-love-music-and-how-sound-effects-us/