# Change audio's frequency, but still sound similar

Tags: frequency, cd, file-conversion, program, 48khz

I have some WAV format audio files with a frequency of 48Khz and I want to load them into the program I'm making. The program however only accepts up to 44.1Khz (CD music quality) due to hardware restrictions, so I need some way to convert my audio file's hz. To be clear I don't think this is pitch shifting like [this question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/25865/converting-music-frequencies) says because I want the files to sound about the same rather than sounding deeper.

Ideally I'd like to use a commandline tool that just takes in the WAV files and outputs new 44.1KHz options so I can automate the build process (And if it can handle other formats like OOG, thats a bonus). Also I'm not terribly familiar with sound terminology so there might be a super obvious answer I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are dealing with is the *sampling frequency* or *sampling rate* of your audio files. And what you want to achieve is called *sample rate conversion*.

There are many software that can deal with this process. Two examples come to mind to automate the process :

- [SoX](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html)
- [FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html)

Simple example with Sox that will convert in.wav sample rate to 44.1 kHz and save it as out.wav :

```
$ sox in.wav --rate 44100 out.wav
```

Comment: Ah ofc sampling frequency. I'll install SoX and try it out later tonight. Thanks :)